# how can i get the size or weight from images url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, screen-scraping, mechanize

referring to the previous question [methods width and height Mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447571/methods-width-and-height-mechanize)

I would like to know how can I get the size from web page image's with Mechanize.

I have created a method for use like helper but the process is very slow, e.g.

```
url = "http://www.birchbox.com"
page = Mechanize.new.get(url)
images_url = page.images.map{|img| img.url.to_s }.compact
```

This is the helper method:

```
def check_image_size
  images_urls.each do |image_url|
   image = MiniMagick::Image.open(image_url)
   if image[:width] < 100
    images_urls.delete("#{image_url}")
   end
  end
return images_urls
end
```

This method removes all images from the array if they have a smaller width of 100px.

**The problem with this method is that the process is very slow. My page takes too long to load with this method.**

**Is there any quick and easy way to do this with Mechanize?**

Comment: When you says < 100, do you mean the real size of the image, or the way it would appear to someone if they viewed the page. They're not the same.

Comment: I refer the real size of the image :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the real size of the image, you're going to have to fetch it.

As you noted, that can take a long time. One way to hasten this would be to not fetch the whole image but instead fetch it progressively and parse it as it comes. You can stop reading the image as soon as you have enough of it to determine its size.

That's fairly complicated and probably won't work all the time, since for some image types you'd need to fetch the image fully in order to know the size (I think).

Comment: My principal problem its that Mechanize get images with pixel size of **1x1** or images as icons, avatars that I do not want to show ...etc. I need filters this images. E.g. images like **spacer.gif** its blank space for layout old web pages. Then I want to know how can I filter this images type...

Comment: There's no easy answer to what you're asking for. You don't even want the real image size, you want the size as shown (since a big image can be shown small and visa versa.) That requires interpreting CSS (and possibly javascript). You can do that with headless browser (there are a few based on webkit). But like I said, it's all non-trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Fast Image](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage)

> FastImage finds the size or type of an image given its uri by fetching
>   as little as needed

And then...

```
images.each do |src|
         size = FastImage.size(src)
         puts "width: #{size[0]}"
         puts "height: #{size[1]}"
     end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with smparkes, it's complicated enough that it probably wouldn't give you a speed advantage. But here are some ideas to speed things up:

- Check the filesize. Download the image to a temp file first and you
  will be able to skip anything smaller than 1Kb or so.
- Analyze the filename. you know to skip spacer.gif but how about names
  like my_tiny_image_20x20.gif
- Download concurrently. It's tricky but you can use eventmachine to
  download the images at the same time.
- Implement a cache. Once you identify the width of an image save it in
  a db so you can just look it up next time.

Comment: Thank you I think that I have the fix for this problem. when developing the solution, I will post it :D